# tmlib.jsでLoadingSceneを使わずにアセットを読み込む方法は？

Tags: tmlib.js

tmlib.jsのバージョン0.3にて画像や音をロードする際に、`tm.scene.LoadingScene`を利用していますが`tm.scene.LoadingScene`を使わず動的にアセットを読み込む方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `LoadingScene`を利用せず、アセットとして管理されるリソースを読み込む方法を知りたいということでしょうか。`tm.asset.Loader`で可能かと思いますが、この辺り0.2.0で大きく変わっているので、利用されている`tmlib.js`のバージョンを明記した方が答えやすいと思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
バージョンは0.3となります。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tm.asset.Loader#load()`](http://phi-jp.github.io/tmlib.js/docs/index.html#!/api/tm.asset.Loader)にて動的に読み込むことができます。

`tm.scene.LoadingScene`の実装も`tm.asset.Loader`でリソースを読み込ませている間に、ヒヨコを回転させているだけだったりします。

以下、あまり実用的ではないですがコード例です。

```
tm.define("HogeScene", {
  superClass : "tm.app.Scene",

    init : function() {
    this.superInit();
    // LoadingSceneで読み込んだ画像を表示
    this.sprite = tm.display.Sprite("initial",200,200);
    this.sprite.setPosition(100, 100);
    this.addChild(this.sprite);

    var self = this;
    this.addEventListener("pointingend", function(e) {
        // タッチイベント時にtm.asset.Loader()で読み込み
        var loader = tm.asset.Loader();
        loader.onload = function() {                
            self.sprite2 = tm.display.Sprite("dynamic",200,200);
            self.sprite2.setPosition(300, 100);
            self.addChild(self.sprite2);
        };
        loader.load({
            "dynamic":"dynamic.png",
        });
    });
},
```

アセットとして利用可能になるのは`onload`の後になります。非同期処理によってコードの見通しが悪くなる可能性がありますのでご注意下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！基本は`LoadingScene`を利用しますが、そうでない場合があったので助かります。